# Update multiple rows Foreign Key with select form

Tags: php, sql, pdo, jquery-chosen

I have 3 tables :

> files(file_id,name,etc..),
>   groups(group_id,name,etc...) and
>
> file_group(file_id,group_id)=> Using foreign key here with the primary
>   keys from both tables(files and groups).

My issue is : I'm having trouble to make an update on my table `file_group`.

> Error message : Integrity constraint violation : 1062 Duplcate entry
>   '40-6' for key PRIMARY....

I know why it's telling me that but I still cannot make it work.

The code is:

```html
<form method="post" action="edit.php">

<select multiple="multiple" name="groups" class="form-control" >
   <option value=1>Admin</option>
  <option value=2>project_1</option>
  <option value=11>Project_Bio</option>
  <option value=12>Project_3</option>
  <option value=20>Project_Off</option>
  <option value=22>Project_zed</option>
</select>
</form>

<?php
$id = 40;

if(!empty($_POST)){

  //signleton to get the table where i want to make the update
  $fc = $app->getTable('fc');

  $new_grps = $_POST['groups'];

  foreach($new_grps as $k => $new_grp){
    $fc->update($id,[
      'group_id' => $new_group
    ]);
  }
}


?>
```

In my table `file_group`, a file can have 2 groups.
So, the code is trying to make the same update with the same data. For me it seems like the loop doesn't work!

Any tips?

The `Var_dump();` gives the following:

```
array(2){
   [0]=>string(1)"11" 
   [1] =>string(2)"20"
}
```

Data Table structures :

```
--
-- Table structure for file
--
CREATE TABLE files (
  file_id SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  description TEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  owner VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  date DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
  last_update TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY  (file_id),
  KEY idx_title (title)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Table structure for table `groups`
--

CREATE TABLE groups (
  group_id TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
  last_update TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY  (group_id)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Table structure for table `file_group`
--

CREATE TABLE file_group (
  file_id SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  group_id TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  last_update TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (file_id, group_id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_file_group_file FOREIGN KEY (file_id) REFERENCES files (file_id) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT fk_film_group_group FOREIGN KEY (group_id) REFERENCES groups (group_id) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: `var_dump($_POST);` and what do you see? Does the data make sense? If you try and run the command through a SQL IDE or shell, does the query work? You don't show how you actually POST the data to the server. Can you either edit that code into the question or edit the results of the `var_dump` into the question?

Answer (score 0):

It such cases you have to use database transactions. Once you start a transaction, you update the foreign key columns and then commit.

```
<?php
$id = 40;
if(!empty($_POST)){
    //signleton to get the table where i want to make the update
    $fc = $app->getTable('fc');
    $new_grps = $_POST['groups'];
    updateForeign($new_goups,$fc); 
}

function updateForeign($new_groups,$fc){
    //$dbh is your database connection
    $dgh = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=myDB", $username, $password);
    $dbh->beginTransaction();
    try{
        foreach($new_grps as $k => $new_grp){
                $fc->update($id,[
                    'group_id' => $new_group
                ]);
        }   
    }
    catch(\Exception $e){
        $dbh->rollback();
        return false;
    }
    $dbh->commit();
    return true;
}

?>
```

Remember, you have to get the PDO database connection instance in the function`updateForeign()`.

Comment: I tried your solution but it returns false. And if I remove the "try catch" I'm getting the same error message : Integrity violation duplicate entry

Comment: Then the problem is not with foreign keys. It's with primary key. Check whether you are duplicating the primary key values

Comment: I added the data table structures. And I think the error is with php and not with the tables...